# Convert dates into a new format

Tags: php, regex

I have a document with a bunch of dates, always wrapped in  tags and always in a specific format.

```
$text = '...<dt>31 DEC 1793</dt>... ...<dt>14 JAN 1934</dt>...';
```

I'm trying to replace this text to include the day of the week:

```
$text = '...<dt>Tuesday, 31 DEC 1793</dt>... ...<dt>Sunday, 14 JAN 1934</dt>...';
```

Right now I'm trying to use preg_replace to achieve this, but it just gives me the current date.

```
$text = preg_replace('/<dt>(\d{1,2} [A-Z]{3} \d{4})<\/dt>/i', "<dt>".date('l', strtotime("$1")).", $1</dt>", $text);
```

It seems like the date function just runs once, instead of each time a replace happens. How could I make this work?

Comment: Why not use `date_format()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the `date` and `strtotime` functions inside a callback:

```
$text = '...<dt>31 DEC 1793</dt>... ...<dt>14 JAN 1934</dt>...';
$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<dt>(\d{1,2} [A-Z]{3} \d{4})<\/dt>/i',
    function ($matches) {
        $date = $matches[1];
        return "<dt>".date('l', strtotime($date)).", ".$date."</dt>";
    },
    $text
);
// $text = '...<dt>Tuesday, 31 DEC 1793</dt>... ...<dt>Sunday, 14 JAN 1934</dt>...';
```